# How do you display visio diagram in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to know if there is a free alternative to display Visio diagram (.vds file) in webforms asp.net C#?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you look into [this](https://github.com/saveenr/VisioAutomation)

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, the only way to go is using ActiveX, but if you decide to go down that path, do know that it's supported only by Internet Explorer, and since that one is going to the grave rather quickly I'd say you'll give yourself some headache quite quickly.

There's no pure HTML5/ASP.NET WebForms solutions for this as per today.